# I can't run the app on my device error type 3

Tags: java, android

Im making an android application and when i run it on my device i get error with launch activity

```
"Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.smartirrigation/com.example.smartirrigation.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.smartirrigation/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.smartirrigation/com.example.smartirrigation.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity"
```

I'v tried disabling the instant run and checking the launch activity

Comment: Does it run OK in an emulator? By the looks of the logcat, it seems like the MainActivity class is missing. What does your manifest look like, and what namespace does your MainActivity.java belong to?

Comment: @Kartik Why was my edit suggestion rejected? As per the [tag:android-studio] tag guidance, the tag shouldn't be used for general Android questions.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut It was rejected because you had omitted the first line `Error while executing......`. Happy to remove android-studio tag if you like.

Comment: @Kartik Huh, don't know why that disappeared, but I was certain that I only added backticks to the body. Understandable, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the MainActivity.java class doesnot exist. that is what the error says. 
try

1. Refactoring name of the class
2. Rebuild the project.
3. Invalidate cache and restart and launch the app.